# html flooded with ahref tags

Tags: html

I am coding a frontend page for my website, and its run by code igntier, but right now is basically just HTML / CSS in a view file.

The problem I am having is that I have a "notifications" box, that looks fine in all of my PHP editors (I mainly use sublime text 2 but i check my code for clean indentation in php eclipse and notpad++) but when I open it with a browser, every DIV has a /a above it, and every comment is wrapped with a

I search "HTML flooded with ahref" on google, and it just brought up news on the new york flooding from hurricane sandy, like that helps me at all.

I have social media connected to the HTML, but I removed it and the  tags remained there.

I have google chrome extentions for norton, and my finger print scanner, and i disabled them and no help.

I removed all jquery from my page except the src="jquery.js" that pulls in jquery source.

I have even also tried renaming all of the notifications class names, and no help.

Please help! Heres some source code:

```
 <div class="notifications">
                <a href="#">Notifications <span class="notify-number">2</span></a>

                <div class="notifications-container">

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/uploads-user.-pics-sample.-pic1.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right' id="blah">Your friend <span>Alex</span> changed their profile picture.</div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/images-icons-calendar.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right'>"2012 Ending Giveaway" is ending in a day or less! <a href="#">Check it out here!</a></div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/images-icons-document.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right'>There are new tutorials for you to view! <a href="#">Check here to view tutorials!</a></div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/images-icons-video.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right'>There is new videos for you to view! <a href="#">Check here to view videos!</a></div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/images-icons-video.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right'>Your friend <span>Izikea</span> added a new video! <a href="#">Check here to see it!</a></div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/images-icons-document.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right'>Your friend <span>Izikea</span> added a new tutorial <a href="#">Check here to see it!!</a></div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                    <div class='notification'>

                        <div class='notification-left'><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>misc/image/images-icons-post.-wall.png/40/40"></div>
                        <!-- End notification Left -->

                        <div class='notification-right'>Your friend <span>Izikea</span> posted on your wall <a href="#">Check here to see it!!</a></div>
                        <!-- End notification right -->

                        <div class='notification-close'><a href="#">X<a></div>
                        <!-- End Notification Close -->

                        <div class="spacer"></div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- End Notification -->

                </div>
                <!-- End Notifications Container -->

            </div>
            <!-- End Notifications -->
```

This is the social media that I have on the page.

```
 <div class="social-media">

                    <div class="facebook-like-button">
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.grosource.com" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="twitter-follow-button">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/GroSource" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @twitterapi</a>
                        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                    </div>
                    <div class="twitter-tweet-button">
                        <a href="http://www.grosource.com/" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
                        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                    </div>

                    <div class="google-plus-button">
                        <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
                        <g:plusone size="medium" href="http://www.grosource.com/"></g:plusone>

                        <!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                          (function() {
                            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                          })();
                        </script>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Let me know if you need more.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3):

Wrong closing tag.

```
<a href="#">X<a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="#">X</a>
```

Should have closing tag, not openning at the end.
Check fot others. I saw at least 3.

Comment: Thank you!! That is such a noob mistake. I just switched to Sublime Text and it doesnt auto complete end tags unless I hit tab when the auto complete list is open. Thanks so much!